# How send checkbox value equal 0 if not selected alpinejs?

Tags: alpine.js

I am using Alpinejs and i can't figure out how send value 0 if checkbox is no checked. One of way is create on background full array with default zeros and update on 1 what frontend sent.

```
<input id="check_1" type="checkbox" value="check_1" x-model="data.locations">
<input id="check_2" type="checkbox" value="check_2" x-model="data.locations">
```

in this code above i have value like this

```
array(
    0 => 'check_1'
);
```

or
array(
0 => 'check_1',
0 => 'check_2'
);
but if first checkbox is checked and second checkbox is not selected i would like to get

```
array(
    'check_1' => 1,
    'check_2' => 0,
);
```

is this possible using alpinejs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can transform the data as you like. Assuming you have an array, e.g. `all_locations` with all possible checkbox values, you can use a function like:

```
getLocations() {
  return this.all_locations.reduce((acc,curr) => {
    acc[curr] = this.data.locations.includes(curr) ? 1 : 0
    return acc}, {})
},
```

It will return an object, where the selected checkbox values will set to 1, and the unchecked ones to 0.